# Уравнение линейной регрессии в R

Tags: r

Привожу упрощенный пример, чтобы более понятно объяснить ситуацию.

Пример: в магазине "A" (файл A) есть 1000 арбузов, у каждого своя цена и вес. Чтобы составить уравнение линейной регрессии нам необходим результат функции lm.

В этом случае мы используем:

> a <- lm(data=A, formula = price~wigth) потом summary(a) и вуаля...

Но не всё так просто) У арбузов есть еще для примера есть параметр - страна, где они были выращены ("Turkey" and "Spain"). Так вот понимаю что вопрос очень простой, но я уже замахался искать решение. Как мне написать линейное уравнение регрессии с использованием функции lm только для арбузов из "Turkey" или только "Spain".
Вернее куда и как включить этот параметр в 
a<-lm(data='A',formula=price~wigth???????)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a <- lm(data=A[A$country=='Turkey',], formula = price~wigth)
```

Answer (score 2):

У функции `lm()` есть аргумент `subset` специально для этого

```
lm(data = mtcars, hp ~ wt, subset = cyl==4)
```